# How to trace method, System.gc(), in Oracle JRE

Tags: jakarta-ee, garbage-collection

I have an application that I know is doing explicit GC calls: `System.gc()` or `Runtime.gc()`.  I've verified this by disabling explicit GCs using `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` and the full GCs go away.

I've checked the code and don't seem to find the `System.gc()` or `Runtime.gc()` call anywhere.  It's a large project, so it's possible I've missed it or it's being called in some library.

I know with the IBM JRE you can run [traces](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.60%2Fdiag%2Ftools%2Ftrace_options_activation.html) on methods.

Example:

```
-Xtrace:trigger=method{java/lang/System.gc,javadump}
```

Is it possible to do the same with the Oracle JRE to help find where it's being called?  I don't have the ability to run this in debug mode with a breakpoint. :(

Also, I know it's not NIO or RMI making these GC calls.

Comment: Which OS is running the JVM?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using AOP to define an @Before pointcut for those methods, then create an Exception object and either throw it or log/mail it's stacktrace.  Note that you could inspect the stacktrace to only take action on relevant cases (i.e. experiment a bit locally to figure out what a 'normal' non-explicit stacktrace might look like).

Answer (score 0):

You could :

- profile the application with e.g. **jProfiler**, then you can search through the collected trace to find the `System.gc()` calls.
- collect thread dumps in the time when you expect a Full GC to occur, this could show you the stack trace triggering the System GC.